# Как правильно добавлять существующие проекты в решение в Visual Studio 2019? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, сборка, nuget

Хочу сделать одно решение, где будет несколько проектов, после чего добавить их в VCS(GitHab). Несколько проектов уже написано. Проект представляет из себя одно решение, где есть несколько проектов касательного самого задания и проект тестов. Так вот, начал добавлять в только созданное решение(библиотека классов) эти проекты через - Добавить - Существующий проект - выбираю нужный **.csproj** файл. Добавляю. Потом начинают сыпаться одни и те же ошибки: *данный проект ссылается на пакеты nuget отсутствующие на этом компьютере*. Окей, посмотрел на какие пакеты NuGet ругается, установил их. Пересобрал - ничего, та же ошибка. Это первая проблема. Вторая - я сомневаюсь, что правильно их вообще добавляю, потому что я зашел через проводник в папку самого решения, а там ничего не появляется(кроме ссылок на проекты, как я полагаю), а если я потому буду загружать это на GitHub(при этом первоисточник, где находятся проекты, может быть удален и т.д., хочется, чтобы в новом решении были копии проектов, а не ссылка на них).

Comment: Если у вас все нужные вам файлы в одной папке, то вы добавляйте проекты как хотите, на github будет залита вся папка все равно.

Comment: Вообще это с архитектурой что то не так похоже у вас, зачем разделять на проекты. При таком подходе, как описано "траблы" обеспечены. Либо объединить в один проект. Либо, если у вас есть два проекта, которые выполняют различные задачи, то тогда лучше организовать микросервисную архитектуру.

Comment: @tym32167 может я не совсем точно описан конечную цель - хочу объединить несколько репозиториев на github в один. Поэтому подумал, что надо в одно решении собрать все проекты и загрузить на github

Comment: @Vladimir ответил коментом выше

Comment: Если вам надо нескоько репозиториев в один собрать, гуглите сабмодули ([submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules))

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо, то,что нужно.